# How can I import information for an HTML file into another HTML file using HTML

Tags: html

I have two files, lets say a.html and b.html, both in the same folder. 'a' contains information that i want to be seen in 'b', when it is opened. How can I do that using only HTML?

Comment: Unless you use a frame/iframe, you cannot have one html file "include" another one. html isn't a programing language that can do such a thing. You'd need server-side tools (e.g. SSI, php, etc...) to directly load one file into another.

Comment: If you want to link to `b.html`, you use `<a href="b.html">link to b</a>`.  If you want to "embed" `b.html` into the body of `a.html` you don't do that without javascript.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer can you tell me how it can be done with javascript.
I just started writing html and i still don't know many things.

Comment: Switching the files to PHP would allow you to embed one in the other if that is available to you...

Comment: @DrCord to be specific using most server side language would allow to you manipulate the HTML document more fluidly

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't just include 2 HTML files together using only HTML

Comment: also can you elaborate on what exactly you want included in the other HTML file so people can help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using [HTML Import](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

In your index file, you include an import to your page by simply adding

`<link href="import.html" rel="import" />`

To use the content of an import use the `.import` property.

`var content = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;`

To make use of a certain element.

```
var elm = content.querySelector('.your-class-to-use');
```

But take note, it's not being supported on all browsers [check here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports).

Comment: this is technically an HTML5 feature but requires JavaScript to use the content, so this isn't an HTML only method of importing files...

Answer (score 0):

Per comment on question, the way to embed a second HTML document into the first using javascript looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $.get("b.html", function( data ) {
      $("#target").html(data);
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>this is a title</h1>
  <div id="target"><!-- dynamic content will be put here --></div>
  <p>
    You can put any other html you like in the rest of the document
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I used jquery here instead of raw javascript, because it abstracts differences in browser behavior, wraps potential errors and is therefore easier to get started with.